# React router anchor tag href is showing 404 error

Tags: html, reactjs, anchor, react-router-dom

I have a react project. I set up routes using react router dom. Now I used Link for navigating the pages but Link doesn’t reloading the page or component. So I used default html anchor tag. It does work in localhost, but when I upload on server, it is showing page not found. is there any way to solve this?

Comment: Could you add your code? Please ;-)

Comment: Add your code we cannot help without seeing your code please only upload specific code also

Answer (score 1):

Please show your code but dont use anchor tag in with react-router-dom use Link tag that comes with it , if you use anchor tag, your application won't remain SPA

```
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom'
//and use it like this for example
<Link to="/about">About</Link>
```

for more info check [Official docs](https://reactrouter.com/web/example/basic)

Comment: it is not mandatory to use `Link` but it is Recommended but the app does have to work with `<a>` also